# C++ To count the occurrences of a char in a string using find(str, index)

Tags: c++, string, count, find

This is actually my homework and the question states:

> "The program should determine how many times the character is
>   contained in the string. (Hint: Search the string by using the
>   find(str,ƒind) method. This method should be used in a loop that
>   starts the index value at 0 and then changes the index value to 1 past
>   the index of where the char was last found.)"

This is what I've came up with but all it does is count how many character there is in the string. New to C++ so I hope you guys can be patient with me.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    char c;
    size_t contain;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter a string : ";
    getline(cin, s);
    cout <<"Enter a char : ";
    cin >> c;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        contain = s.find(c, i);
        if (contain =! string::npos )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder what you are really using `find` for? perhaps if you used the `contain` variable to jump in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @parapura's code looks nice'er like this:

```
while((size_t contain = s.find(c,i)) != string::npos){
    count++;
    i = contain + 1;
}
```

and it solves the problem nicely ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
(contain =! string::npos)
         ^^
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B.

Also, this:

```
contain = s.find(c, i);
```

doesn't do anything particularly useful (if all you're doing is incrementing `i` every iteration).  You'll end up counting some occurrences multiple times.

[***Note:*** You can solve the actual task much more cleanly by using `count = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c)`.]

Comment: Yea.. But the question insisted on me using find(str, index)

Comment: @NewUserSeekingHelp If that is so you will need to adjust the way you move on to the next character: you only want to search from the found character onwards.

Answer (score 4):

**You can do simply :**

---

*Instead of*

```
contain = s.find(c, i);
if (contain =! string::npos )
    {
        count++;
    }
```

*Write*

```
if(s[i] == c) 
{
   count++;
}
```

---

*also, you can use this.*

```
#include <algorithm>
int count = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
cout<<count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think according to your problem statement.

> changes the index value to 1 past the index of where the char was last found

Your while loop should be something like

```
while( 1 )
{
    contain = s.find(c, i);
    if (contain != string::npos )
    {
        count++;
        i = contain + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```